# signature and date dotline formatting

Tags: formatting

I'm trying to create a statutory declaration and have problems with the dotline. Now it is something like that:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{lmodern}


\begin{document}


\addsec[tocentry={}]{Eidesstattliche Erklärung}

Hiermit erkläre ich an Eides statt, dass ich die vorliegende Arbeit selbständig und ohne Benutzung anderer als der angegebenen Hilfsmittel angefertigt habe; die aus fremdem Quellen direkt oder indirekt übernommenen Gedanken sind als solche kenntlich gemacht.\\
Die Arbeit wurde bisher in gleicher oder ähnlicher Form keiner anderen Prüfungsbehörde vorgelegt und auch noch nicht veröffentlicht.


\vspace{35mm}


\begin{flushleft}
    \begin{minipage}[c]{5cm}
        \centering \dotfill \\
        Ort, Datum
    \end{minipage}
\end{flushleft}

\begin{flushright}
    \begin{minipage}[c]{5cm}
        \centering \dotfill \\
        Unterschrift
    \end{minipage}
\end{flushright}


\end{document}
```

[image]

How is it possible to place that dotlines in the same height?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{lmodern}


\begin{document}


\addsec[tocentry={}]{Eidesstattliche Erklärung}

Hiermit erkläre ich an Eides statt, dass ich die vorliegende Arbeit selbständig und ohne Benutzung anderer als der angegebenen Hilfsmittel angefertigt habe; die aus fremdem Quellen direkt oder indirekt übernommenen Gedanken sind als solche kenntlich gemacht.\\
Die Arbeit wurde bisher in gleicher oder ähnlicher Form keiner anderen Prüfungsbehörde vorgelegt und auch noch nicht veröffentlicht.


\vspace{35mm}


\noindent\begin{minipage}[c]{5cm}
        \centering \dotfill \\
        Ort, Datum
    \end{minipage}
\hfill
    \begin{minipage}[c]{5cm}
        \centering \dotfill \\
        Unterschrift
    \end{minipage}


\end{document}
```